# QueryRow().Scan() returns an error if row wasn't found. How to solve?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem.

I have a struct:

```
type Token struct {
    Id             *int64     `db:"id"`
    Email          *string    `db:"email"`
    OperationType  *string    `db:"operation_type"`
    Token          *string    `db:"token"`
    ExpirationDate *time.Time `db:"expiration_date"`
}
```

I have a function which finds one token by email:

```
func (r Repo2) FindOneByEmail(ctx context.Context, email string, ct *Token) error {
    row := r.DB.QueryRow(`
        SELECT id, email, operation_type, token, expiration_date 
        FROM tokens 
        WHERE email=$1 AND type=$2 AND expiration_date>$3::date`,
        email, "registration", time.Now(),
    )

    err := row.Scan(&ct.Id, &ct.Email, &ct.OperationType, &ct.Token, &ct.ExpirationDate)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Some fields in db can be null (that is why I use pointers in struct)

But when I do .Scan, it throws error (as value is null it can't take address "&")

But if I remove "&", It throws error too "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

**So how can I solve this problem?**

The idea is: If if finds a row, it needs to get fields values, but if row was not found it needs to throw sql.ErrNoRows

Comment: If you're using the standard library and a sensible driver, then, if the query returns no row `QueryRow` will return `sql.ErrNoRows` *as documented*. If there's no row, there's no scanning, if you have problem with scanning then that means that a row was returned by that query. So which is it?

Comment: QueryRow returns *row, I can't find out if it was not found only after scan. Here is comments in library: // If the query selects no rows, the *Row's Scan will return ErrNoRows.

Comment: `Scan` knows about no-rows or some-rows, by calling Scan the row object checks whether there is anything to scan, if not it returns ErrNoRows *before doing any scanning*, if yes it will scan the rows into the pointers provided.

Comment: Ok, so if I remove Scan, how can I get error?

Comment: You can't, why would you remove Scan?

Comment: May be I didn't understand you correctly. In my situation when I do Scan it thows error (not sql.ErrNoRows)

Comment: To clarify, your QueryRow and Scan code is correct, you're doing exactly what you should do. The question is why is everything a pointer, is every column NULLable? No? Maybe change some pointer fields to non-pointer fields then? Yes? Why? Why is id NULLable?

Comment: It throws error, that he can't Scan as one of returned values is nil and he can't get & of nil

Comment: Ok, let's say that only several fields can be null. It does not change situation

Comment: The situation is: 1) I have a field in DB which can be null. 2) If I use & in Scan and there is nil, it will throw error. 3) If I don't use &, I will get "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

Comment: Use `sql.NullXxx` types for nullable columns, you don't have to have them in your original struct, you can choose to use them only for scanning/writing and then assign the result to your struct's instance. You get the benefit of getting rid of pointers in your fields.

Comment: Alternatively, use `COALESCE` in your SQL query, then you can leave out `sql.NullXxx` types and pointers from your Go code.

Comment: But there is no Null type for time.Time and in my situation this field can be null

Comment: There is if you create one ;)

Comment: Yes, it is true :D But I thought that NullType is the same as pointers

Comment: Just take a look at how the other Null types are implemented and you'll see it's very easy to pull off. If you don't want to do it yourself try https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#NullTime

Comment: Yes, I know that pg lib has it. I use pgx and I don't know why there is now null time (I use pgx for a long time, but found this problem today)

Comment: Ok, so I think I should: 1) remove all pointers from my struct 2) write my own null time 3) use null type in scan

Comment: If possible you could test that query and code with `lib/pq`, it's possible that the `pgx` driver and the `pq` driver handle pointer fields differently. I know for a fact that lib/pq can handle nil-pointers-to-null-columns at least in some cases if not all...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BAxB7Wr as stated in the previous comment `lib/pq` knows how to handle pointer fields. So it seems this is a driver specific issue, and therefore you have now at least 3 options, use NullXxx types, use COALESCE, or change drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for pgx Driver:

Remove pointers from struct

```
type Token struct {
    Id             int64     `db:"id"`
    Email          string    `db:"email"`
    OperationType  string    `db:"operation_type"`
    Token          string    `db:"token"`
    ExpirationDate time.Time `db:"expiration_date"`
}
```

Rewrite function

```
func (r Repo2) FindOneByEmail(ctx context.Context, email string, ct *Token) error {
    var date pgtype.Timestamptz

    row := r.DB.QueryRow(`
        SELECT id, email, operation_type, token, expiration_date 
        FROM tokens 
        WHERE email=$1 AND type=$2 AND expiration_date>$3::date`,
        email, "registration", time.Now().UTC(),
    )

    err := row.Scan(&ct.Id, &ct.Email, &ct.OperationType, &ct.Token, &date)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    ct.ExpirationDate = date.Time

    return nil
}
```